# Как обобщить события?

Tags: java, android, generics, события

Здравствуйте!
Есть класс `Event`, у него есть наследники `LoginComletedEvent`, `LoadingCompletedEvent` и тд.

Есть интерфейс слушатель, с методами

```
 void onEventReceived(LoginComletedEvent event);
 void onEventReceived(LoadingCompletedEvent event);
...
 void onEventReceived(SomeEtcMethod event);
```

Как мне организовать отправку какого то определенного события, не создавая для каждого наследника `Event` отдельный метод?

Что то в роде :

```
public <T> void post(Class<? extends Event<T>> eventClass) {
        for (EventListener e : listeners) {
            e.onEventReceived(eventClass);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За вас уже все давным-давно придумали. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Если хотите сами изобрести этот же велосипед, то вытягивайте через рефлексию сигнатуру всех методов EventListener'a, и проверяйте, есть ли метод, принимающий в качестве параметра ивент данного типа.